# Is std::ranges::size supposed to return an unsigned integer?

Tags: c++, eigen, c++20, eigen3, std-ranges

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) it is written that `std::ranges::size` should return an unsigned integer. However, when I use it on an *Eigen* vector (with Eigen 3.4) the following compiles:

```
Eigen::VectorXd x;
static_assert(std::same_as<Eigen::VectorXd::Index,
                           decltype(std::ranges::size(x))>);
```

where `Eigen::VectorXd::Index` is notoriously a signed integer. By looking at the implementation of `std::ranges::size`, I noticed that the return type is inferred from the return type of `x.size()`, which is precisely `Eigen::VectorXd::Index`. Is this a bug of `std::ranges::size`? Or is this expected?

---

**Update 27/12/2021**

The C++ reference page linked above has eventually changed the description of the `std::ranges::size` function: it only returns an *integer*, not necessarily an unsigned one!

Comment: A container's `size()` method is supposed to return an unsigned integer. The problem is at the Eigen's side.

Comment: `Otherwise, t.size() converted to its decayed type, if ranges::disable_sized_range<std::remove_cv_t<T>> is false, and the converted expression is valid and has an integer-like type.` Looks like underspecified for containers which return signed types for sizes.

Comment: When the call is valid, if no user-defined `size()` functions is involved, it returns an unsigned integer (or integer-class) value. Otherwise, it returns the return value of that `size()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a bug of std::ranges::size?

No. The cppreference documentation is misleading. There is no requirement for `std::ranges::size` to return an unsigned integer. In this case, it returns exactly what `Eigen::VectorXd::size` returns.

For ranges that model `ranges::sized_range`, that would be an unsigned integer, but `Eigen::VectorXd` evidently does not model such range.

> But then what is the purpose of std::ranges::ssize compared to std::ranges::size?

The purpose of `std::ranges::ssize` is to be a generic way to get a signed value regardless of whether `std::ranges::size` returns signed or unsigned. There is no difference between them in cases where `std::ranges::size` returns a signed type.

> Is there a reference to back up what you state?

Yes. See the C++ standard:

> [range.prim.size]
>
> Otherwise, if `disable_­sized_­range<remove_­cv_­t<T>>` ([range.sized]) is `false` and `auto(t.size())` is a valid expression of integer-like type ([iterator.concept.winc]), `ranges​::​size(E)` is expression-equivalent to `auto(​t.size())`.

Comment: But then what is the purpose of `std::ranges::ssize` compared to `std::ranges::size`? Is there a reference to back up what you state?

Comment: Also, `Eigen::VectorXd` *does* satisfy the `std::ranges::sized_range` concept!

Comment: @fdev See edited answer for your first comment. `Eigen::VectorXd does satisfy the std::ranges::sized_range concept` I disagree; It doesn't satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Actually it does: the only requirements to satisfy the `std::ranges::sized_range` concept are that `Eigen::VectorXd` is a range (which it is since Eigen 3.4) and that `std::ranges::size` can be called on `Eigen::VectorXd` objects.

Comment: To be fair, the cppreference documentation just mention that [`std::ranges::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/size#Notes) *"Whenever ranges::size(e) is valid for an expression e, **the return type is integer-like**."*, while [`std::ranges::ssize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/ssize#Notes) *"If ranges::ssize(e) is valid for an expression e, **the return type is a signed-integer-like type**, i.e. an integer type for which std::is_signed_v is true, or a signed-integer-class type. "*

Comment: @Bob__ Yeah, those are accurate. The misleading part is on the ranges library page linked in the question.

Answer (score 7):

It's very much intended that the `sized_range` concept and the corresponding `ranges::size` customization point take no position on the signed/unsigned holy wars. `ranges::size` does convert to unsigned when computing from the distance between begin and end, for consistency with the existing standard library, but user types are not required to agree with that choice.

Comment: Too bad, I feel it would be better if `std::ranges::size` always returned an unsigned integer and `std::ranges::ssize` always an unsigned one! Why not? What is the point?

Comment: @fdev not part of standardization so IDK, but I guess maybe they did ranges before they agreed on ssize